# Possible values of a $f(x)=(ab-b^2-2)x+\int_{0}^{x} x^2(\cos^{4}t+\sin^{4}t)\mathrm{d}t$

Tags: calculus, integration, functions

Suppose $f(x)=(ab-b^2-2)x+\int_{0}^{x} x^2(\cos^{4}t+\sin^{4}t)\, \mathrm{d}t$ is a decreasing function of $x$, $x$ is a real number. What are the possible values of $a$?
$b$ is independent of $x$.

I tried Newton Leibniz formula. How should I proceed after that?

Comment: I'm assuming $\cos^{4t}$ should be $\cos^4t$?

Comment: @BrianFitzpatrick this could be an exotic operator ;)

Comment: $\cos^{4t}$ must be $\cos^4t$ for otherwise no variable for integration.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}
\int_{0}^{x} (\cos^{4}t+\sin^{4}t)\, dt&=\int_{0}^{x} ((\cos^{2}t+\sin^{2}t)^2-2\cos^{2}t\sin^{2}t)\, dt
\\
&=\int_{0}^{x} (1-\sin^{2}{2t}/2)\, dt
\\
&=x-\dfrac1{4}\int_{0}^{x} (1-\cos{4t})\, dt
\\
&=\dfrac{3}{4}x+\dfrac1{16}\sin{4x}
\end{align}
So 
$$
f(x)=(ab-b^2-2)x+\dfrac{3}{4}x^3+\dfrac{x^2}{16}\sin{4x}
$$
And 
\begin{align}
f'(x)&=(ab-b^2-2)+\dfrac{9}{4}x^2+\dfrac{x}{8}\sin{4x}+\dfrac{x^2}{4}\cos{4x}
\\
&=(ab-b^2-2+2x^2+\dfrac{x}{8}\sin{4x})+\dfrac{x^2}{4}(1+\cos{4x})>0
\end{align}
for large $x$. 
So there are no $a,b$ for $f$ to be a decreasing function.

Comment: Why are you considering large $x$ only ? $f'(0)=ab-b^2-2$ can be negative, isn't it ? Could you please clarify for me ? Thanks.

Comment: It says $f$ is a decreasing function for all $x$. So I just prove that is impossible since for large $x$, $f'>0$. $f'(0)$ is trivial.

Comment: I do not see *for all* $x$. I totally agree with you for large $x$.

Comment: If not for all $x$, it should specify what $x$. The question is not precise.

Comment: Be sure that I fully agree with you. The question is effectively not precise. Cheers :-)

Comment: When you look at $g(x)=\frac{1}{16} x^2 (4 \cos (4 x)+12)+\frac{1}{8} x (12 x+\sin (4 x))$ it is always $\geq 0$ and $f'(x)=(ab-b^2-2)+g(x)$. So, it is sufficient that $ab-b^2-2 <0$ to have a portion of the function which decreases. End of the story, I bet. Cheers.